# Recyclerview make the last added item be the selected item?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal Recyclerview which displays bitmaps. 
The Way it is implemented is I have a Imageview and a recyclerview underneath it. The currently selected item is displayed on the image view. The selected image view is given a blue background to indicate it is selected. I can choose images from the gallery and each time a new image is selected, I want to scroll to the last position and make the item selected.

The list of images is maintained in a array list and each time a new image is added, I add the image to the list and notifyDataChanged().

Currently when I am binding a view, I toggle the visibility of the blue background in

public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
}

But the problem is, if the child is off screen, the bind view is not called and I dont scroll to the new position. 
I read through the documentation of recycler view and could not figure out how to scroll to that particular child view. I do not there is a SmoothScrollTo method but my question is where do I trigger this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is one solution:

1. In your `RecyclerView` adapter, add a variable `selectedItem` and a methods `setSelectedItem()`:

   ```
   private static int selectedItem = -1;

    ... ...

   public void setSelectedItem(int position)
   {
      selectedItem = position;
   }
   ```
2. In your `onBindViewHolder(...)`, add:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) 
   {
      ... ...

      if(selectedItem == position)
         holder.itemView.setSelected(true);
   }
   ```
3. Now you can scroll to specific item and set it selected programmatically by:

   ```
   myRecyclerViewAdapter.setSelectedItem(position_scrollTo);
   myRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position_scrollTo);
   ```

For example, you want to scroll to last position and make it selected, just:

```
    int last_pos = myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() - 1;
    myRecyclerViewAdapter.setSelectedItem(last_pos);
    myRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(last_pos);
```

[**UPDATE**]

To add item and make it selected, you should have a `addItem(...)` method in adapter, which will add item to item list. After adding item, refresh list and scroll to new added/latest item:

```
myRecyclerViewAdapter.addItem(...);
myRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
myRecyclerViewAdapter.setSelectedItem(myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() - 1); 
myRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(myRecyclerViewAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: The problem is not actually being able to scroll to a certain position. The problem is being able to scroll to it right after the item has been added .

When ever a new Item is added, I get the new list of data, I tell the adapter I have new data by calling the function notifyDataChanged() . If I call scrollToPosition and the position it will crash because the view has not been created yet and we are trying to scroll to it.

Comment: @Shrek, look my **UPDATE**, now after adding new item, it is selected. I have tested the codes and work fine. Any further problem just tell

Answer (score 2):

Your view will not be created until you scroll to the item.

You must call

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)
```

Where position is

```
 recyclerView.getAdapter().size()
```

So the item became visible.

Comment: When ever a new Item is added, I get the new list of data, I tell the adapter I have new data by calling the function notifyDataChanged() . If I call scrollToPosition and the position it will crash because the view has not been created yet and we are trying to scroll to it.

Comment: Why dont you add the item to your current list and notify only rows inserted?

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView LayoutManager to scroll item at position

```
recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position)
```

I forgot to address the timing part ideally this should be called when the adapter has been identified of the dataset change.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```